# get mean value of multiple columns per row excluding specific columns with pandas

Tags: pandas, mean

I have a file with 25 columns (id and values for 24 hours) as following:

```
id  H1  H2  H3  H4  H5  H6  H7  H8  H9  H10 H11 H12 H13 H14 H15 H16 H17 H18 H19 H20 H21 H22 H23 H24
1   324 321 289 235 302 300 337 329 327 303 335 317  -9999  341 317 324 289 338 318 310 324 251 304 327
2   322 315 329 321 331 337 342  -9999  313 332 290 307 321 318 337 316   0 155 288 314 257 313 320 336
3   322 121 123 213 286 282 157 304 205 264 286 315 315 327 341 343 263 209 321 288 56  87  279 278
4
```

I want to get the mean daily (mean of 24 columns per row) but excluding the values with "-9999" and "0". How I could add this statement in the following code which estimates simple the mean of all columns?

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(file,sep='\t',skiprows=(0),usecols=[*range(1,25)])
df_mean=df.mean(axis=1)
df_mean.index = df_mean.index+1 
df_mean.to_csv(outfile,sep='\t',header=False)
```

Comment: Probably just change your second line to `df_mean = df.mask(df.isin([-9999, 0])).mean(1)` to exclude 0 and -9999 from the mean. Unclear if your `id` is the index, so you'd need to select `.iloc[:, 1:]` if it's not.

Comment: @ALollz you should post your comment as answer, It's been two times already that I read the question before realizing your gave an answer as comment ;)